# Updating table through while and for loop

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to sort out the delete function for my private messaging section of my site, basically it deletes the message fine, but i am now trying to get it to not only delete the message, but all the other reply messages that are connected to it, through a while loop, each individual message has a unique message_id, but each "conversation" of messages such as where replys are involved, there is a message_unique which is the same id for every message connected via each other.

Here is the delete code below, all it needs to do is set a variable to one where the reply is from the recipient, or set the delete variable to one if it form the sender, hopefully you should get what i mean, at the moment it is setting both the sender_deleted and recipient_deleted to 1 which it shouldn't

```
if (isset($_POST['delete_inbox'])) {

foreach($_POST['inbox_select_box'] as $message_unique) //loop through the checkboxes
{

 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE message_unique = $message_unique");

      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
          extract($row);

 if ($recipient_id == $user_id){
     $sql = "UPDATE messages SET recipient_deleted = '1' WHERE message_unique = '$message_unique'";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
 }
 else{
     $sql = "UPDATE messages SET sender_deleted = '1' WHERE message_unique = '$message_unique'";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
 }


      }

}
```

$user_id is the global variable for the id of the user who is logged in, thanks for any help you guys can give me

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is the DB not being updated, do you get errors...?

Comment: Hi, no the problem is that it is not updating the DB properly, it is setting both the recipient_deleted and sender_deleted to 1 where it should only be setting one of them to 1, that part id controlled by the if statement

Comment: But it is performing the wrong update on the correct rows? So no problem with which messages need to be updated?

Comment: the messages being updated are fine, the problem is that for example on one of the messages i tested being deleted had both the recipient_id and sender_id set to 1 where it should have been just the recipient_id

Comment: Why are you selecting the rows before updating them? Is it necessary?

Comment: Because i need to loop through the messages, for example, if there are 5 replies, then it needs to loop through each 5 and determine for each one whether the recipient_id or sender_id needs to be set to 1, the select query just selects all the messages that are connected to the one being primarily deleted

Comment: I am trying to send a message in the chat, but for some reason it is not submitting any of my comments, in reply to your question the primary key is message_id, which is unique for every single message, the message_unique is to identify a collection of different messages such as replys etc...

Comment: No problem. Then I assumed correctly. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your primary key is called something like `message_id`.
Try it like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete_inbox'])) {
    foreach($_POST['inbox_select_box'] as $message_unique) //loop through the checkboxes
    {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE message_unique = $message_unique");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            extract($row);
            $message_id = $row['message_id'];
            if ($recipient_id == $user_id){
                $sql = "UPDATE messages SET recipient_deleted = '1' WHERE message_id = '$message_id'";
            }
            else
            {
                $sql = "UPDATE messages SET sender_deleted = '1' WHERE message_id = '$message_id'";
            }
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem was, that you were setting the value on every message in the thread every time. You need to perform the update with the actual id of the message for every row.

As a side note: if you are simply setting a SQL string to use in `mysql_query()` you should perform the method call only once outside your `if () ... else ...` statement.

Comment: ok brilliant, that works great, just to save some extra time, if you don't mind, if i was to also insert each message/reply into a seperate table such as mail_trash, could i just add it after the if else, or actually in the if else - here is the code for the insert - `$sql_trash = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mail_trash (message_id, reply_id, message_unique, deleter_id, sender_id, recipient_id, mail_date_sent, time_mail_deleted) 
     VALUES('$message_id','$reply_id','$message_unique','$user_id','$sender_id','$recipient_id','$mail_date_sent', now())")  
     or die (mysql_error());`

Comment: You should also add that after the `if () ... else ...` statement, because it should be done in both cases. Otherwise you would have duplicate code, which should only be done if there is absolutely no other way.

Comment: Another approach for that would be to set a trigger on your messages table, that inserts the values into the trash table as soon as either `recipient_deleted` or `sender_deleted` are set to 1. That way it would be done automatically.